# explicit computation of fractional Laplacian of a function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integration

For $x\in\mathbb R$ let
$$
u(x)=\begin{cases}
|x|^{2s-1}-1  &\mbox{if }  |x|>1,\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Is it possible to calculate explicitly the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{s} u(x)$ for a fixed $s\in (0, 1/2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is, as long as you are OK with special functions. See Corollary 3(ii) in my paper with B. Dyda and A. Kuznetsov titled *Fractional Laplace operator and Meijer G-function*, [DOI:10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4). Here one needs to apply this result twice, with $d = 1$, $\alpha = 2 s$, $l = 0$, $\sigma = 0$ and $\rho$ equal to either $s-\tfrac12$ or $0$.

---

Edit: To clarify, the result mentioned above implies that
$$ (-\Delta)^s \bigl[|x|^{2\rho} (|x|^2-1)_+^\sigma\bigr] = 2^{2s} \Gamma(1+\sigma) G^{1,2}_{3,3}\biggl(\begin{array}{ccc}\tfrac12-s & 1+\rho+\sigma-s & -s \\ 0 & \rho - s & \tfrac12 \end{array} \; \bigg\vert \; |x|^2\biggr) . $$
If we set $\sigma = 0$, we find that
$$ (-\Delta)^s \bigl[|x|^{2\rho} \mathbb{1}_{|x|>1}\bigr] = 2^{2s} G^{1,2}_{3,3}\biggl(\begin{array}{ccc}\tfrac12-s & 1+\rho-s & -s \\ 0 & \rho - s & \tfrac12 \end{array} \; \bigg\vert \; |x|^2\biggr) . $$

For $\rho = 0$, we get
$$ (-\Delta)^s \bigl[\mathbb{1}_{|x|>1}\bigr] = 2^{2s} G^{1,2}_{3,3}\biggl(\begin{array}{ccc}\tfrac12-s & 1-s & -s \\ 0 & -s & \tfrac12 \end{array} \; \bigg\vert \; |x|^2\biggr) , $$
which simplifies to
$$ \frac{\Gamma(2s) \sin(\pi s)}{\pi} ((|x|^2-1)^{-2s} - (|x|^2 + 1)^{-2s}) $$
when $|x| > 1$ (and to a similar expression when $|x| < 1$).

On the other hand, for $\rho = s-\tfrac12$ we find that
$$ (-\Delta)^s \bigl[|x|^{2s-1} \mathbb{1}_{|x|>1}\bigr] = 2^{2s} G^{1,2}_{3,3}\biggl(\begin{array}{ccc}\tfrac12-s & \tfrac12 & -s \\ 0 & -\tfrac12 & \tfrac12 \end{array} \; \bigg\vert \; |x|^2\biggr) = 2^{2s} G^{1,1}_{2,2}\biggl(\begin{array}{ccc}\tfrac12-s & -s \\ 0 & -\tfrac12 \end{array} \; \bigg\vert \; |x|^2\biggr) , $$
which, for $|x| > 1$, is equal to
$$ \frac{\Gamma(2s) \sin(\pi s)}{\pi |x|^2} ((|x|^2-1)^{-2s} + (|x|^2 + 1)^{-2s}) . $$

The result is found by subtracting the above two expressions:
$$ (-\Delta)^s u(x) = \frac{\Gamma(2s) \sin(\pi s)}{\pi |x|^2} ((|x|^2 + 1)^{1-2s} - (|x|^2-1)^{1-2s}) $$
for $|x| > 1$ (unless I made an error when manipulating these terrible expressions).

Of course, this can be found by direct integration, too. The above method is more involved, but quite general. For example, it carries over to higher dimensions.

Comment: @GabS: I guess you can divide by $(2s-1)$ and pass to the limit as $s \to \tfrac12$, no? (The $s$ in the definition of $u$ need not be the same as the exponent $s$ in $(-\Delta)^s$, if this matters.)

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki Yes, I should have been precise. I would like to calculate $(-\Delta)^{1/2}$. Here $u$ look like the fundamental solution except in a neighbourhood of zero

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki I believe in both the cases the answer is zero as in one dimension, these are fundamental solution away from zero.

Comment: @GabS: No, it is definitely *not* zero, unless $s = 1$. Why do you expect it to be zero?

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki The calculation is  $(-\Delta)^s u(x)= 2^{2s} \frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma((1/2)}{\Gamma(0)\Gamma ((1-2s)/2) } |x|^{-1}= 2^{2s} \frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma((1/2)}{\Gamma (1-2s/2) } |x|^{-1}.$ So I am wrong.

Comment: If you are saying about $(-\Delta)^{1/2} [\log |x|]$, then this is indeed zero (observe $\Gamma(0)$ in the denominator in your expression). However, $(-\Delta)^{1/2} [\log |x| \mathbb{1}_{|x| > 1}]$ is not identically equal to zero.

Comment: I do agree, but I think there is a problem. The function in your paper $u(x)= |x|^{2\rho}(|x|^{2}-1)_{+}^{\sigma}$ considering $V(x)=1.$ The function what I want is a bit more complicated $(|x|^{2(s-1/2)}-1)_{+}$ which need $\rho$ to be zero and $\sigma$ to be $s-1/2$ or may be I am making a mistake.

Comment: I expanded my answer in response to your last comment. If everything remains unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: @GabS: But what are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Simply write $u$ as a linear combination of $|x|^p \mathbb{1}_{|x|<a}$ or $|x|^p \mathbb{1}_{|x|>a}$ for different $p$ and $a$, and you are good to go, right?

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki What is the quickest way to compute the Meijur $G$ function. You are using a  Meijur function and hypergeometric series. Is there a good book on this topic.

Comment: @GabS: "Quickest" in the sense of numerical methods? No idea. *Mathematica* seems to evaluate it reasonably well, but relatively slow. WolframAlpha also is able to evaluate single values. Regarding general introduction to Meijer G-function, I do not have anything to add to what we wrote in the article. Prudnikov's book is perhaps a good start.

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki  In your calculation, I think  $|x|^2$ should be replaced by $|x|.$

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki  Is the fractional Laplacian of  the characteristic  function $\chi_{(1, \infty)}$  and $\chi_{(1, 2)}$ is the same? Do the end point contribute of the calculation.

Comment: If you look at the expression for $(-\Delta)^s u(x)$, then you will clearly see that these are quite different functions for $u = \chi_{(1,\infty)}$ and $u = \chi_{(1,2)}$.

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki If I consider $u(x)=\chi_{1,2}(x)$ and calculate $(-\Delta)^s u=constant\times [(x+1)^{-2s}-(x+1)^{-2s} -(x-2)^{-2s}+  (x+2)^{-2s}]$. If $x\in (1, 2)$ the third term is a bit tricky. Am I wrong.

Comment: Means that  $(x-2)$ is negative when $x\in (1,2)$, then what happens to $(-1)^{1-2s}(2-x)^{-2s}.$

Comment: Do you mean $\chi_{1,2}(x) = 1$ if $1 < |x| < 2$ and $\chi_{1,2}(x) = 0$ otherwise? The expression you gave looks OK for $x > 2$, for general $x$ you need absolute values of $x\pm1$ and $x\pm2$ and appropriate sign corrections.

Comment: Yes, the characteristic function on the interval (1,2).